# Does anyone know any magic command to display wall clock time (i.e. say 21:15:00) of the cell executie on in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-lab

How can I display time of execution of a particular cell in Jupyter Notebook? For example if cell execution started at 21:00 pm, it should display 21:00 pm (or even more precisely) once execution of a particular cell is complete. Is there any magic command for that?

Answer (score 0):

Not very magic:

```
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.now())
```

Comment: To go along with that, I like [this reference](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/06/how-to-get-current-date-and-time-in/) as a guide for formatting `now()` using `.strftime()`.